# Records not getting Inserted in Snowpark

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using below python script to find the table which are not been updated for given interval of time and Insert them in a Notifications Table:

```py
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from datetime import datetime

schemas = ['AW']
database = 'DEV_DB'

create_table_query = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NOTIFICATION_TABLE (
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR,
    FILE_NAME VARCHAR,
    LATEST_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
    SCAN_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
    MAX_AGE INT,
    STATUS VARCHAR,
    MESSAGE VARCHAR
)
""" 

def main(session: snowpark.Session):
    table_notification_intervals = {
    'Table1': 1
    }

    # Process tables in the AW schema
    for schema in schemas:
        print("Processing schema: {0}".format(schema))

        # Get the list of tables and views in the specified schema
        query = "SHOW OBJECTS IN {0}.{1}".format(database, schema)
        objects = session.sql(query).collect()

        for object_row in objects:
            object_name = object_row['name']
            object_type = object_row['kind']

            if object_type == 'TABLE' and object_name in table_notification_intervals:
                print("Processing table: {0}".format(object_name))

                # Check if the table has the FILE_NAME column
                check_column_query = """
                SELECT COLUMN_NAME
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{0}'
                    AND TABLE_NAME = '{1}'
                    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'FILE_NAME'
                """.format(schema, object_name)

                column_result = session.sql(check_column_query).collect()
                if len(column_result) == 0:
                    # Table does not have the FILE_NAME column
                    subquery = """
                    SELECT LAST_ALTERED AS TIME_STAMP
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{0}' AND TABLE_NAME = '{1}'
                    """.format(schema, object_name)

                    result = session.sql(subquery).collect()
                    # latest_timestamp = result[0]['TIME_STAMP']
                    # print(latest_timestamp)
                    if len(result) > 0:
                        latest_timestamp = result[0]['TIME_STAMP']
                        days_since_update = (datetime.utcnow().date() - latest_timestamp.date()).days
                        notification_interval = table_notification_intervals[object_name]

                        if days_since_update > notification_interval:
                            # Generate the data for the notification table
                            
                            table_data = [
                                object_name,
                                 latest_timestamp,
                                datetime.utcnow(),
                                notification_interval,
                                'Not Updated',
                                "The table '{0}' has not been updated for {1} days. Please take action!".format(object_name, days_since_update)
                            ]
                            print(table_data)
                            # Insert the data into the notification table
                            insert_query = """
                            INSERT INTO "AW"."NOTIFICATION_TABLE" (
                                TABLE_NAME,
                                LATEST_TIMESTAMP,
                                SCAN_TIMESTAMP,
                                MAX_AGE,
                                STATUS,
                                MESSAGE
                            )
                            VALUES (
                                TABLE_NAME,
                                LATEST_TIMESTAMP,
                                SCAN_TIMESTAMP,
                                MAX_AGE,
                                STATUS,
                                MESSAGE
                            )
                            VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, '{5}')
                            """.format(*table_data)
                            session.sql(insert_query)
```

Everything seems to be good but records are not getting updated in the table, when I print the `print(table_data)` It gives me all the records as well, could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the actual query is not executed:

```
session.sql(insert_query)
=>
session.sql(insert_query).collect()
```

Second, insert query text is syntactically incorrect:

```
INSERT INTO "AW"."NOTIFICATION_TABLE" (
    TABLE_NAME,
    LATEST_TIMESTAMP,
    SCAN_TIMESTAMP,
    MAX_AGE,
    STATUS,
    MESSAGE
)
VALUES (
    TABLE_NAME,
    LATEST_TIMESTAMP,
    SCAN_TIMESTAMP,
    MAX_AGE,
    STATUS,
    MESSAGE
)
VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, '{5}')
```

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO "AW"."NOTIFICATION_TABLE" (
    TABLE_NAME,
    LATEST_TIMESTAMP,
    SCAN_TIMESTAMP,
    MAX_AGE,
    STATUS,
    MESSAGE
)
VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, '{5}')
```